# Distance a muon travels in a pion rest frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I have a question regarding a pion at rest (with a mean life time of $2.5\times 10^{-8}$ s) which decays into a muon (of mean lifetime $2.2\times 10^{-6}$ s), and a neutrino.

I've found the velocity of the muon, I now need to find the mean distance that the muons travel in the pions rest frame. My thought was to use the time dilation equation to find the lifetime of the muon in the pions rest frame and then use the velocity of the muon which was already found to then calculate the distance in the pions rest frame using distance = speed * time. Would this be correct to do?
Many thanks

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Even though the speed of the muon is in the muon's own frame, this still works? Apologies if this is a stupid question

Comment: No question is stupid. Muon's speed in its own frame is zero. The speed you should use is in the pion's rest frame or lab.

Comment: Ah makes sense, many thanks!